# "Out Of Memory" error in excel VBA for a very large model. How can I avoid this?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying a declare a new variable in VBA for Excel. I have an excel model which has 9 modules and 7 class modules. Each module is really large, with an average of 60 variables declared in each module and a minimum of a few hundred lines of code to a maximum of a couple of thousand lines of code in each module. Every time I try typing a new variable, I get an error that says "Out Of Memory". How can I avoid this error and continue declaring more variables ?

Comment: We have too little information. Please show us the code that generates this error.

Comment: Even when you fix this... if you're getting out of memory errors in Excel I suggest that in the medium term you consider moving to a more scalable platform like SQL Server. Not knowing what your model does it's hard to know how practical this is.

Comment: "Every time I try typing a new variable..."  Is this a design-time error? What you have described is a good-sized VBA project, but by no means too large. Are all of your variables public?

Comment: @RachelHettinger A lot of my variables are global, public as well as private.

Comment: Install office 64bit. 32bits processes are limited to ~2gb memory usage.

Comment: I am using Windows 7, with 64 Bit Office. (excel 2010).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment we have too little data to provide you with a definite answer.

However the reasons may be plenty:

- You are declaring a lot of objects ("Set obj = ") and never cleaning them (Set obj = Nothing). If you do not reduce the reference to an object it will remain in memory.
- You have a loop in which you are declaring a lot of objects/variables until you get a memory Overflow.
- You are creating too many objects at once that allocate too much memory (e.g. IE object etc.)

**How to deal with this?**

- Start with the code that raises the error as most likely this is happening in a loop or another place which increases memory usage (use debugging F8 to traverse code). There may be many solutions depending on the source of your issue.
- Leverage memory statistics throughout different milestones in your code https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e3aefd82-ec6a-49c7-9fbf-5d57d8ef65ca/check-size-of-excelexe-in-memory or simply use the **Task Manager**
- See if any of these tips help: https://www.add-ins.com/support/out-of-memory-or-not-enough-resource-problem-with-microsoft-excel.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I just wanted to let you know that there is no error at run time. As soon as I try declaring a variable, I get the error. 
It's the same with Public, Private as well as local variables(local to a function or a subroutine)

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I try typing a new variable, I get an error that says "Out Of Memory".

This sounds like a design-time error--an error you get when *editing* the code rather than a run-time error that you get when *running* the code.

If indeed this is a design-time error your file may be corrupted. Try rebuilding it by copying all sheets into a new workbook and copying the code into new, blank modules.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are size limits on VBA Forms, Standard, and Class Modules, Procedures, Types, and Variables.

I've only seen it documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa716182(v=vs.60)

You either need to reduce the scope of your program, splitting it in to logical steps. Or use a more robust programming language like VB.NET.